# Is it possible to run the Windows Phone 7.1 emulator in an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-phone-7.1

**Background:**
My firm has a new client who has asked us to build a Windows Phone 7.1 app.  Our team wants to leverage Amazon's EC2 instances to set up our CI servers to avoid the need to have to requisition and acquire hardware for the project.   We will need a Windows build agent to build the Windows Phone app.

**Problem:**
Setting up the Windows build agent is proving difficult. To build the Windows Phone app, we need the WP 7.1 SDK installed, however it is not supported on Windows Server and officially requires Windows Vista or Windows 7.  With a [workaround by Aaron Stebner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx) I can get the SDK installed, but the Windows Phone emulator doesn't work.    We can compile and run unit tests, but functional tests are not possible without the emulator.

- Is it possible to enable to Windows Phone emulator to work on Windows
  Server 2008 or 2008 R2?
- Is it possible to create a Windows Vista or
  Windows 7 instance on EC2?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Windows vista or Windows 7 on EC2. One solution will be to use Virtualbox inside an Ubuntu instance but I don't think it will work because EC2 already use an hypervisor ...

Maybe you can find an other cloud provider or buy a VPS.